# PL/SQL query error that I am running into. I have no clue what could be wrong

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a pl/sql query that fetches certain data and from tables and outputs the data. Here is what I have tried but I keep getting an error and I cannot begin to see where the problem is.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
DECLARE
TEMP_CUSTNAME CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
TEMP_CUSTSURNAME CUSTOMER.SURNAME%TYPE;
TEMP_COINPUR COIN.PRODUCT%TYPE;
TEMP_CPRICE COIN.PRICE%TYPE;
TEMP_DNOTES COIN_DELIVERY.DELIVERY_NOTES%TYPE;
CURSOR CURSOR1 IS 
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME,C.SURNAME FROM CUSTOMER C, COIN.PRODUCT, COIN.PRICE, COIN_DELIVERY.DELIVERY_NOTES
WHERE COIN.PRICE > 8000;
BEGIN 
OPEN CURSOR1;
LOOP
FETCH CURSOR1 INTO TEMP_CUSTNAME, TEMP_CUSTSURNAME, TEMP_COINPUR, TEMP_CPRICE, TEMP_DNOTES;
EXIT WHEN CURSOR1%NOTFOUND;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('CUSTOMER: ' || TEMP_CUSTNAME || ',' ||TEMP_CUSTSURNAME);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('COIN: ' || TEMP_COINPUR || );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRICE: ' || TEMP_CPRICE || );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NOTES: ' || TEMP_DNOTES || );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('------------------------------------' );
END LOOP; 
CLOSE CURSOR1;
END;
```

Comment: Please, post the error code and text and provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should first debug your code by yourself and describe the specific issue you have.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you've provided us with the error you're facing.

So far I see number of fields in the cursor (2) is not the same as number of variables being fetched into (5).

In other words, you need to add more columns here:

```
SELECT C.FIRST_NAME,C.SURNAME FROM CUSTOMER C, COIN.PRODUCT, COIN.PRICE,
```

so there will be enough data to fetch to this variables here:

```
FETCH CURSOR1 INTO TEMP_CUSTNAME, TEMP_CUSTSURNAME, TEMP_COINPUR, TEMP_CPRICE, TEMP_DNOTES;
```

Or, probably, you need to reduce number of variable you're fetching into like this. It depends on result you're trying to achieve

```
FETCH CURSOR1 INTO TEMP_CUSTNAME, TEMP_CUSTSURNAME;
```

UPD. wrong concatenation. Based on the error message from comments I see now there are problems here too. Remove trailing "||" in lines below

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('COIN: ' || TEMP_COINPUR || );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('PRICE: ' || TEMP_CPRICE || );
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('NOTES: ' || TEMP_DNOTES || );
```

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 17, column 51:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: ( - + case mod new null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum
   variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date
   <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
   <an alternatively-quoted SQL
ORA-06550: line 18, column 51:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:

Comment: @ArnoldBunu chek the update answer please